# mbox not valid when using lwip_sendto

Tags: c, freertos, lwip

I am trying to use the lwip stack in freertos for a UDP based communication over multiple sockets. My first problem was, that socket creation failed because, `lwip_socket` has a call to `netconn_new`, which contains a call to `TCPIP_APIMSG(&msg)`, which returned with an error. I figured out that the error in `TCPIP_APIMSG(&msg)` was produced because `sys_mbox_valid(&mbox)` returned false.

I could solve the problem after recognizing that I created more UDP sockets than allowed by the lwip configuration variable `memp_n_udp_pcb`. I just increased `memp_n_udp_pcb`.

Now I have the problem that `lwip_sendto` stops working after sending about 300 packets. Again, an invalid mbox in `TCPIP_APIMSG(&msg)` seems to be the reason. `lwip_sendto` calls `netconn_send`, which calls `TCPIP_APIMSG(&msg)`, which returns an error due to an invalid mbox.

I am only trying to use the lwip stack with freertos, but I have no experience with the implementation details of the lwip stack. I have no idea what the invalid mbox means and how to solve the problem.

I hope someone can explain to me what is going wrong here.
Are there any further settings (except `memp_n_udp_pcb`) I have to change when using more than the predefined number of 4 UDP sockets?
Why does `lwip_sendto` fail after sending a few hundred packets without problems?

Comment: Best to ask/search lwip question on the discussion list: http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lwip-users/